# How to match data in multidimensional array of post_meta_data?

Tags: array, post-meta

I am saving user id in post meta whenever someone clicks on like button.

```
        $voter = Array(
                        voter => array(
                        'post_id' => $post_id,
                        'user_id' => $user_id,
                        'user_ip' => $user_ip,
                        'author_id' => $author_id,
                        'vote'    => $vote
                        )
                    );  
        add_post_meta($_POST['post_id'], 'voter', $voter);
        echo "success";
```

I want to run this only if user does not already liked the post. So I used this:

```
function in_array_r($needle, $haystack, $strict = false) {
    foreach ($haystack as $item) {
        if (($strict ? $item === $needle : $item == $needle) || (is_array($item) && in_array_r($needle, $item, $strict))) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Then using if condition like this helps me to find if user id is already in meta data or not.

```
$voter_info = get_post_meta( get_the_ID() , 'voter', false );
if (in_array_r("1533", $voter_info)){
                        echo "User is in post meta";
                    }
```

But the problem is this condition is searching for user id: 1533 in all array values. I want to search it in the 'user_id' field. This is making me confused. If you have solution on this or if you know any better way to search in multi dimensional array, then please help me.

Comment: Try this func. http://pastebin.com/EhcX2JrQ . I suppose `voter` is an index ( in 1st snippet ), 'cause it looks like a constant and I guess that's a typo so.

Comment: This works for me. Thank You Samuel Elh. Can you add it as answer please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple PHP related question (and those are better asked at StackOverflow.com) and you can find if an index exists within a multi-dimensional array by iterating through it and matching.
Something as:

```
function wpse231889_has_user_voted( $user_id, $post_id ) {
    if ( !empty( ( $voters = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'voter' ) ) ) ) {
        foreach ( $voters as $voter ) {
            if ( !empty( $voter['voter']['post_id'] ) && (int) $user_id == (int) $voter['voter']['post_id'] ) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    } return false;
}
```

Glad it helped.